# How to make uiview fullscreen viewcontroller using custom transitions ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

What i want to achieve is: after tapping a small view with some data i want to make it full screen and possibly make it to be a new vc.

For now I animate uiview to full screen with great success, but whole logic of this view is in it's "parent".

Is it possible to animate viewcontroller out of the uiview which is similar (for. eg. like in LayoutTransitions in Android SDK)?

Sample code of my uiview to full screen using autolayout:

```
            sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                             animations:^{
                                 sender.view.frame = self.view.window.bounds;
                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 [((CSTicketView*)sender.view) showMenu];
                             }];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
             setStatusBarHidden:YES
             withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
            [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Absolutely possible.
You can use the new view controller transitions model in iOS7.
I would definitely recommend a few resources to check on top of my basic explanation:

- [this](http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2013/12/17/building-better-transitions-with-ios-7/)
- and [this](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?path=//videos/wwdc/2013/index.php?id=218&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757)
- I have some sample code for a demonstrator of this [here](https://bitbucket.org/cocoadelica/zoomatron/)

Ultimately you make a new view controller for the view you are transitioning to, and you also make an NSObject subclass that conforms to UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning which contains the code to transition between them. Sounds complex but if you watch the video I linked to and read the other reference it'll make total sense.

Comment: Zoomatron doesnt work. it has project.pbxproj missing.

Comment: my bad, will fix that :)

Comment: OK< I pushed the project file, give that a try

Comment: all links are dead

Comment: All links are broken.

Comment: Please consider updating the links. As mentioned they are all dead

Answer (score 0):

Let's move your sender view to Window as like below,

```
AppDelegate * appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate.window addSubview:sender.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                             animations:^{
                                 sender.view.frame = self.view.window.bounds;
                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 [((CSTicketView*)sender.view) showMenu];
                             }];
```

Comment: csticketview is already on screen. I want the view to become uiviewcontroller while animating.

Comment: OK, Once animate complete, let's initiate your UIViewController with your CSTicketView. Example: viewController.view = sender.view;